# Clarification on the location of stress and strain output value in Abaqus

Tags: finite-element-method, simulation, abaqus

Today, I had a discussion with my teacher about the location of stress and strain output in Abaqus. I believe that Abaqus outputs stress and strain based on Gauss integration points. However, my teacher insists that it is based on mesh nodes.

My argument is based on the information provided by the program found at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54919-abaqus2matlab. According to the program's documentation, the dimensions of exported strain or stress in MATLAB are "where #n# is the number of elements multiplied by the number of integration points," as shown in "Rec21.m." But my teacher claims that this program may not be reliable since it's not an official tool and insists on referring to the official documentation.

I checked "Abaqus 6.11 Analysis User’s Manual," Part II: Output, as shown in the attached image:

[image]

However, based on the statement "See Part VI, 'Elements,' for a definition of the components for a given element type," I couldn't find compelling evidence to support that Abaqus outputs stress and strain based on Gauss integration points.

Now, I am uncertain about the correctness of my understanding, and I need help. Can anyone provide clarification and possibly refer me to official documentation regarding how Abaqus handles stress and strain output, whether it is based on Gauss integration points or mesh nodes?

Comment: You seem to have the official documentation, so read it.

Comment: @SolarMike Sure, I understand. I am currently reviewing the documentation again to ensure I didn't miss any crucial information regarding whether Abaqus uses Gauss integration points or mesh nodes for stress and strain output. My initial read didn't clearly indicate one way or the other, so I hope to find the evidence.